# Compute the product of two square matrices of boolean values

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication

Can someone please give me some guidance on this question: **Write a program that computes the product of two square matrices of boolean values, using the OR operation instead of + and the AND operation instead of *.**

The way I understand matrix multiplication, if you have say the following 2 matrices A: 3x3, B: 3x3, C1,1 would be the sum of (A1,1*B1,1), (A2,1*B1,2), (A3,1*B1,3). What I don't get is how to do this with only the AND and OR operands.

Oh and please don't write the whole program for me... I need to do this myself else I won't learn. :)

Comment: The question means **replace** "+" with "OR" and "*" with "AND".

Comment: I know, but how am I going to add values together with AND and OR

Comment: The question means **literally** replace...

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `+` by `||` and `*` by `&&`:

(A1,1 && B1,1) || (A2,1 && B1,2) || (A3,1 && B1,3)

Assuming that && and || are your AND and OR boolean operators, respectively.

Comment: But AND and OR are used for conditions in loops and + and * are adding and multiplying values. How am I going to add and multiply without using + and *

Comment: @user1213994 AND and OR can be viewed as sum and product operators. **Try it**

Comment: @user1213994: Add an example of what you tried to your question.

Comment: I haven't tried doing the question because I don't know how... from what I understand you're telling me that 5+5 is the same as 5 && 5

Comment: @user1213994 First write the program with + and * in your question, you will need to do this anyway. Then I'll modify one line to handle boolean values as an example.

Comment: @user1213994: 5 isn't a boolean value.

Comment: I know it's just an example... tried it with one and zero and it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

its a boolean expression so your not exactly adding or multiplying values, as boolean can only be 0 and 1 (`0 usually = false and 1 usually = true`). So like it was said above replace the + with or and the * with and and use that to get your boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code works for 2-by-2 boolean matrix. but can't say for higher square matrix.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Boolean Matrix Multiplication {
       public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number : ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        boolean[][] b= {
                        {true, false},
                        {false, true}
                       };   
        boolean[][] a= {
                        {false, true},
                        {true, false}
                       };
        boolean[][] c = new boolean [n][n];

        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k<n; k++){
                   c[i][j] = (a[i][k] && b[k][j]) ||(a[i][n-k-1] && b[n-k-1][j]);
                 }
                   System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
             }
                System.out.println();
        }

  }
}
```